# Joining two Tables in SQL, but using an earler Row if no Result on the right Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have got these three tables in MySQL:

```php
+----------------------------------------------+
| ComputerConfigs                              |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| ConfigID | ComputerID | LastChangeDate | ... |
+----------+-----------------------------------+

+-------------------+
| Software          |
+------------+------+
| SoftwareID | Name |
+------------+------+

+-----------------------------------------------------+
| ComputerHasSoftware                                 |
+------------+----------------------------------------+
| ComputerID | ConfigID | SoftwareID | LastChangeDate |
+------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Each time, a ComputerConfig changes, there will be written a **new row** into `ComputerConfigs`. So I am able to see all changes from the past, too.

Now I am trying to also track the changes of the software. This does not happen that often, so I only want to save new rows into the `ComputerHasSoftware` table, if somebody has really added or deleted something.

I would like to write a query, which returns all `ComputerConfigs` (from the past till now) **with** the software that has been installed. So if there wasn't added a row into `ComputerHasSoftware` belonging to a `ComputerConfig`, then it should take the latest one **before** the timestamp of the ComputerConfig.

I thought about doing a query like this, which simply joins the three tables with each other:

```sql
SELECT 
FROM ComputerConfigs
LEFT OUTER JOIN ComputerHasSoftware
             ON ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID = ComputerConfigs.ComputerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Software
             ON Software.SoftwareID = ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID
```

But as you can imagine, this query leads to a wrong result, because it relates old software to computers, which does not belong there. Changing the join condition to `ComputerHasSoftware.ConfigID = ComputerConfigs.ConfigID` also won't work, because then it misses the ones where no data has been provided and instead it should fall back to the latest one available.

How can I modify my query in order to achieve this? Or is there even a better solution using subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is limitted in the *tricks* it can employ to speed this up.  Using a correlated sub-query *will* work, but you'll need to check performance.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ComputerConfigs
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ComputerHasSoftware
    ON ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID = ComputerConfigs.ComputerID
    AND ComputerHasSoftware.LastChangeDate = (
                                              SELECT MAX(LastChangeDate)
                                                FROM ComputerHasSoftware
                                               WHERE ComputerID = ComputerConfigs.ComputerID
                                                 AND LastChangeDate <= ComputerConfigs.LastChangeDate
                                             )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Software
    ON Software.SoftwareID = ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID
```

Comment: I almost shat my pants because of that great response and I have no idea how you managed to read and understand my post, deliberating an over 15 lines response using my column names and typing it in under 10 minutes! -- Luckily performance won't be an issue in my case because there are <200 `ComputerConfigs`, one computer will have not more than 20 new softwares in a month and there won't be more than 10 concurrent users. Thank you very, very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select  gap date periods:

```
select 
   ConfigID
  ,f.LastChangeDate as fromDate
  ,coalesce( min( t.LastChangeDate ), now() ) as toDate
from 
  ComputerConfigs f
     left outer join
  ComputerConfigs t 
    on f.ComputerID = t.ComputerID
where
  t.LastChangeDate > f.LastChangeDate
group by 
  ConfigID, f.LastChangeDate
```

Then join it in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM ComputerConfigs
LEFT OUTER JOIN ComputerHasSoftware
             ON ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID = ComputerConfigs.ComputerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( above subquery) S
             ON S.ConfigID = ComputerConfigs.ConfigID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Software
             ON Software.ComputerID = ComputerHasSoftware.ComputerID and
                Software.LastChangeDate between S.fromDate and S.toDate
```

Notice that you should replace `above subquery` by my first query. In your question I have not understand if you need a `between` condition or a `<`  or `>` condition. Be free to accommodate query to your needs.
Enjoy.

Comment: If multiple software changes occur between config changes this will pick them all up, giving multiple records for the same config change. I have no idea if that's desired or not; if it is, then good spot :)

Comment: Although, there is a corner case this doesn't like... If there is a software change on the exact same date as a config change, that software change will be assign to both *that* config change, *and* the subsequent config change.

Comment: @Dems, your are right. Be free to change, in my post, `between` by your favorite condition in order to avoid the corner case. Regards.